# Prove that if $17 \not\mid n$, then either $17 \mid n^8+1$ or $17 \mid n^8-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Question is :
Let $n$ be a natural number not divisible by $17$. Prove that either $n^8+1$ or $n^8-1$ is divisible by $17$.

I tried to solve using Fermat theorem for a prime number $p$, and any integer $a$, $a^p-a$ is divisible by $p$.

Then $n^{17}-n$ is divisible by $17$.

Or $n(n^{16}-1)$ is divisible by $17$.

But here, I can't go further.

Comment: Factor $n^{16}-1$ as a difference of squares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you found implies that $n^{16}-1$  is divisible by $17$.
But $n^{16}-1 = (n^{8}-1 ) \cdot ( n^{8} + 1)$.
Can you go on from here?

You can also do a proof by contradiction.

Comment: oh! Now I get!! :)) Thank you so much. How could do a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Assume 17 does not divide any of these two: $ (n^{8}-1 ) $ and $ ( n^{8} + 1)$. You will somewhat easily get a contradiction.

Comment: @Ryu I noticed that you accepted, but not upvoted this answer. If the answer is useful to you, then you are strongly encouraged to upvote. See for instance: [Why is voting important?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)